# AllenNLP Reading Comprehension results are different in UI Demo and Python Library

Tags: python, nlp, allennlp

I am trying `AllenNLP reading comprehension` with the `Transformer QA Model` to get the answer to question `"Who is CEO of ABB?"` from the passage `"ABB opened its first dedicated global healthcare research center for robotics in October 2019."`.

As expected, the UI demo shows `no answer returned`. The API response in network tab also shows that. In the json response, `best_span_str` is empty, but `best_span_scores` is `9.9`. [Screenshot of demo UI and API response in network tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS3qJ.png)

When I execute the similar code via python library, I get a different result.

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
import pandas

def allen_nlp_demo_1():
  import allennlp_models.structured_prediction
  import allennlp_models.rc
  predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/transformer-qa-2020-05-26.tar.gz")
  data = predictor.predict(
    passage="ABB opened its first dedicated global healthcare research center for robotics in October 2019.",
    question= "Who is CEO of ABB?"
  )
  print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  allen_nlp_demo_1()
```

provides following json output

```
{
  "span_start_logits": [...],
  "best_span": [
    7,
    15
  ],
  "best_span_scores": -10.418445587158203,
  "loss": 0,
  "best_span_str": "healthcare research center for robotics in October 2019",
  "context_tokens": [...],
  "id": "1",
  "answers": []
}
```

Here I see `best_span_str` coming up, and `best_span_scores` as `-10.418445587158203`.  [Attaching python code and output snippet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJoSy.png)

Why is this difference in output in the UI demo vs library? Also, what is the range of `best_span_scores` and where can I decide a threshold to discard false results?

Answer (score 2):

1. Regarding the discrepancy in the demo's output and your run, it is because the actual demo uses a different archive file. The usage code on the demo has been updated now to reflect the new file path (`transformer-qa-2020-10-03.tar.gz`).
2. For finding the best_span, the model considers a prediction of cls token to mean that the question is not answerable. This is indicated by `best_spans`, which is [-1, -1] when the question is not answerable. For the case when the question is actually answerable, the span scores are relative to each other; we pick the span with the highest score. So, there isn't a fixed threshold that can be used in all cases.